# What Interlocked.CompareExchange is used for in the dapper .net method?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, dapper

In dapper code in `Link.TryAdd` method, there is the following piece of code:

```
var snapshot = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref head, null, null);
```

Why is this required instead of simple:

```
var snapshot = head;
```

both lines do not change the value of `head`, both lines assign the value of `head` to `snapshot`. Why the first one was chosen over the second?

**Edit:** the code I'm referring to is here: https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/blob/77227781c562e65c167bf7a933d69291d5bdc6f3/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They want to do a volatile read however there is no overload of `Thread.VolatileRead` that takes a generic type parameter. Using `Interlocked.CompareExchange` this way achieves the same result.

The problem they are trying to solve is that the JIT compiler can optimize away the assignment to a temp if it sees fit. This can cause threading problems if another thread mutates the head reference while the current thread is using it in a sequence of operations.

Edit:

The issue is not that a stale value is read at beginning of `TryAdd`. The problem is that on line 105 they need to compare the current head to the previous head (held in `snapshot`). If there is an optimization then there is no `snapshot` variable holding the previous value and `head` is read again at that point. It is very likely that `CompareExchange` succeeds even though head might have changed between lines 103 and 105. The result is that a node in the list is lost if two threads call `TryAdd` simultaneously.

Comment: I have added the link to the code in the question body. I'd like to understand why this optimization would matter in this case. Ok, let's say that the assignment is optimized. What this practically means is that snapshot variable might get a stale value. So what's the big deal, lines 105 - 106 in the code take care of this particular problem, by re-trying if this is the case. Also note that line 105 will force the variable (`head`) refresh, so that the code does not stuck in the loop because of an optimization. Can you describe a scenario in this particular example when the code breaks?

Comment: Yep, makes sense. I'll meditate on this a bit more before accepting the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

mike z is right: This is preventing a (legal) JIT optimization that would break the code.

They could have used the **volatile struct trick**, though: Read `head` and assign it to a volatile field of some struct. Next, read it from that field and it is guaranteed to be a volatile read!

The struct itself doesn't matter at all. All that matters is that a volatile field was used to copy the variable through.

Like that:

```
struct VolatileHelper<T> { public volatile T Value; }
...
var volatileHelper = new VolatileHelper<Field>();
volatileHelper.Value = head;
var snapshot = volatileHelper.Value;
```

Hopefully, it has no runtime cost. In any case, the cost is less than an interlocked operation which is causing CPU memory coherency traffic.

Actually, the fact that every cache access (even a reading one) requires memory coherency traffic makes this a **slow cache**! Interlocked operations are a system global resource that does not scale with more CPUs. An Interlocked access uses a global hardware lock (per memory address, but there is only one address here).

Comment: I don't think this will exactly work since head is passed by ref. so the assignment `volatileHelper.Value = head` will suffer from exactly the same problem that `var snapshot = head` assignment would suffer. The changes in head can went undetected even though volatileHelper.Value is volatile. Am I wrong?

Comment: @zespri, why would they go "undetected"? Btw, this trick is used by the BCL in .NET 4.5. The class is called something like "Volatile..." or so.

Comment: Because head itself is not volatile.